# Winforms checkbox Databinding problem

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, data-binding, checkbox

In a winforms application (VB, VS2008 SP1) i bound a checkbox field to a SQL Server 2005 BIT field.

The databinding itself seems to work, there is this litte problem:

user creates a new record and checks the checkbox, then the user decides to create a new record (without having saved the previous, so there are 2 new records to be submitted) and checks also the second.

Now the user decides to save these records: the result is that only the second record keeps the checked value, the first one is unchecked! (i tried the same with 5 records: the result is the same, the first 4 records are unchecked and only the last one keeps the checked state).

What do i miss??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in winforms binding mechanism. There're more like these around (numericupdown, menu item checks bindings, etc).

You can probably workaround by registering an event on switching to another row, and manually read it from the UI and put into the table.